# Registros duplicados con consulta Inner Join

Tags: php

estoy realizando una consulta con inner join ya que necesito los datos de cinco tablas, mi problema es que al realizar la consulta, se duplican los registros de las tablas, en este ejemplo la tabla de datos personales se duplican, sin embargo de la tabla formaciones no, y al añadir mas tablas abajo estas tambien se duplican. No se como solucionarlo, deberia usar un while o algo?
Aqui mi codigo:

```
<?php
 $Connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proyecto1","root","");
 $statement = $Connection->prepare("SELECT
        usuarios.*, datospersonales.*, formacion.*
    FROM usuarios
    INNER JOIN datospersonales ON usuarios.documento = datospersonales.documento
    INNER JOIN formacion ON usuarios.documento = formacion.documento
    WHERE
        usuarios.documento = :mi_parametro");

$statement->execute([
    'mi_parametro' => $_SESSION['usuario']['documento']
]);
$registros = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
    ?>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <!-- Primera tabla-->
       <div class="box-header"><h3 class="box-title"> Datos Personales </h3></div>
       <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                    <table class=" table table-hover"> 
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                     foreach ($registros as $registro) {
                    ?>
                      <tr><th> Cedula de Identidad </th>
                      <td><?= $registro->documento ?></td></tr>
                      <tr><th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                      <td><?= $registro->fnacimiento?></td></tr>
                     <?php } ?>
                      </tbody></table></div>
        <!-- segunda tabla-->
                <div class="box-header"><h3 class="box-title">Formación y Capacitacion</h3></div>
                <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                 <thead><tr>
                 <th>Titulo</th>
                 <th>Nivel de Estudio</th>
                 <th>Institución</th>            
                 </tr></thead>
                 <tbody>
                <?php
                  foreach ($registros as $formacion) {
                ?>
                <tr><td><?= $formacion->titulo_carrera ?></td>
                <td><?= $formacion->nivel_estudio ?></td>
                <td><?= $formacion->universidad ?></td></tr>
                <?php
                }?>
                 </tbody></table>                            
                </div></div>
   <?php
        } // Cerramos el if
    ?>
```

[image: Mis tablas]

Comment: Hablas de cinco tablas. Quizá convendría que muestres un pequeño data set de cada una de ellas, explicando cómo se relacionan entre sí, y un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener. Si en alguna de las tablas hay por ejemplo relaciones del tipo *uno a muchos*, significa que tendrás que agrupar con `GROUP BY` en la(s) tabla(s) de *muchos*  para que no te repita filas. Sin ver el contexto completo y lo que quieres es difícil darte una respuesta definitiva, lo que sí se puede afirmar es que el problema está en la consulta (y podría estar en el modelo de datos también, pero eso habría que verlo).

Comment: La taba formaciones tiene dos registros y esta al parecer no tiene problemas, ahora con la tabla de datospersonales la relación es uno a uno pero son estos registros los que se duplican. Adjunto la estructura de las tablas! gracias.. @A.Cedano

Comment: No es fácil analizar un esquema que además es incompleto y sin ver datos. Al menos describe en la pregunta cómo se relacionan las tablas entre sí: *La tablaA se relaciona con tablaB de tal forma por tal y tal columna y con tablaC de tal otra forma por tal y tal columna, a su vez tablaC se relaciona con tablaD de tal forma por tal y tal columna*. Si *verbalizas* tu modelo te ayudará incluso a entenderlo y a veces hasta a detectar el fallo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que cuentas, parece que puede haber en una tabla el mismo "documento" y por tanto la unión de tablas hace varias uniones en lugar de una. Verifica que no está duplicado ningún valor para el campo "documento" en ninguna de las 3 tablas. 
Si no es el caso, fíjate en si los resultados duplicados tienen todos los campos iguales. Si tuviesen todos los campos iguales, podrías solucionarlo usando SELECT DISTINCT en lugar de SELECT

Comment: Todas las tablas tienen un campo llamado documento, y con ese campo se relacionan. Entonces tendria que cambiar el sql?. Probe con el SELECT DISTINCT pero sigue igual

Comment: Pero alguna de esas tablas tiene varios registros con el mismo valor en "documento"?

Comment: no, solo el registro "documento" tiene ese valor